# Editable Inputs to a Function in a Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

[image]I want to a shiny app that lets the user test on a function evaluates a set of scenarios using an editable table.  I want the scenarios to be pre-populated, but the user can override the initial values.

I created a minimal app that does everything I want except the initial scenarios are not repopulated.  I would have thought the inputs for the three scenarios would have been pre-populated with 0.05, 0,.1 and .25 and the input and output table would have been computed for each scenario using these values.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(DT)
DCF_dwd <- function(COC) {
  1 / COC
}
x007 <- 0.05


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(h4("Inputs"), DT::dataTableOutput("x1"), h4("Inputs and Outputs"), DT::dataTableOutput("x2")),
  server = function(input, output) {
    x <- reactive({
      x007
    })
    # create a character vector of shiny inputs
    shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
      inputs <- character(len)
      for (i in seq_len(len)) {
        inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...))
      }
      inputs
    }
    
    # obtain the values of inputs
    shinyValue <- function(id, len) {
      unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) {
        value <- input[[paste0(id, i)]]
        if (is.null(value)) NA else value
      }))
    }
    
    tst <- reactive({
      x()
    })
    tst2 <- reactive({
      x() + 0.05
    })
    tst3 <- reactive({
      x() + 0.2
    })
    
    # a sample data frame
    res <- data.frame(
      Scenario1 = shinyInput(numericInput, 1, "Scenario1_", value = tst),
      Scenario2 = shinyInput(numericInput, 1, "Scenario2_", value = tst2),
      Scenario3 = shinyInput(numericInput, 1, "Scenario3_", value = tst3),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
      row.names = c("WACC")
    )
    
    # render the table containing shiny inputs
    output$x1 <- DT::renderDataTable(
      res,
      server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, selection = "none",
      options = list(
        preDrawCallback = JS("function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }"),
        drawCallback = JS("function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } "), dom = "tip",
        bFilter = 0, bSort = 0, bProcessing = 0, bPaginate = 0, bInfo = 0
      )
    )
    
    # print the values of inputs
    d <- reactive({
      cocVec <- c(shinyValue("Scenario1_", 1), shinyValue("Scenario2_", 1), shinyValue("Scenario3_", 1))
      
      out1 <- DCF_dwd(cocVec[1])
      out2 <- DCF_dwd(cocVec[2])
      out3 <- DCF_dwd(cocVec[3])
      
      
      data.frame(Scenario1 = c(cocVec[1], out1), 
                 Scenario2 = c(cocVec[2], out2), 
                 Scenario3 = c(cocVec[3], out3), 
                 row.names = c("WACC", "Sum of DCF"))
    })
    output$x2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(
        d(),
        filter = "none", options = list(dom = "tip", bFilter = 0, bSort = 0, bProcessing = 0, bPaginate = 0, bInfo = 0)
      )
    }) # end RenderDataTable
  }
)
```

I want the inputs to be pre-populated in the screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

`tst`, `tst2`, `tst3` are reactives which means you need to add their values to the table. Currently, you are adding the reactive object (essentially, a function) to the table. If you use the browser developer tools, you can see these generate warnings:

[image]

You need to add the `()` after them in the data.frame to use the values. In order to do this, you also need to make `res` a reactive (i.e. can only access the values of a reactive in a reactive context). Accordingly, you then also have update `output$x1`

```
# a sample data frame
    res <- reactive( # add reactive context
      data.frame(
        Scenario1 = shinyInput(numericInput, 1, "Scenario1_", value = tst()), #instead of just "tst"
        Scenario2 = shinyInput(numericInput, 1, "Scenario2_", value = tst2()),
        Scenario3 = shinyInput(numericInput, 1, "Scenario3_", value = tst3()),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
        row.names = c("WACC")
      )
    )
    
    # render the table containing shiny inputs
    output$x1 <- DT::renderDataTable(
      # res is now a reactive
      res(), 
      server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, selection = "none",
      options = list(
        preDrawCallback = JS("function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }"),
        drawCallback = JS("function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } "), dom = "tip",
        bFilter = 0, bSort = 0, bProcessing = 0, bPaginate = 0, bInfo = 0
      )
    )
```